# (discord.py) How can I make my setprefix command work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The title may seem a little generic so let me explain. My bot uses the prefix `m!` and the way I accomplished this is by adding this line to my code:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="m!")
```

It worked. Now I decided to change how the prefix system worked as I wanted servers to be able to change the bot's prefix. I created a `prefixes.json` file and added the following code:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

I also changed `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="m!")` to this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

And added these so the bot added the server to the JSON file with the default prefix `m!` whenever the bot joined a server.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = "m!"
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)


@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

Essentially, when the bot joins a server, this gets added to the JSON file

```
{
    "<id goes here>": "m!"
}
```

And when the server uses the setprefix command I added, the JSON gets updated with their new prefix.

Here's what the setprefix command looks like by the way

```
@client.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send(f"Prefix changed to: {prefix}")
```

Now, ALL OF THIS CODE works. But only for servers the bot joined AFTER I implemented this. This means that the bot is essentially broken for all of the servers added before because they don't have an entry in the JSON file. **How can I make the bot work in those servers as well?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update `get_prefix` to have a default value:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes.get(str(message.guild.id), "m!")
```